# How I can do this in photoshop - add blue light behind text

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I know it's a lame question most likely but I am new to photoshop and I am currently trying to do a similiar image like this one:

[image]

and I've got this:

[image]

So, basically I'd like to make the light effect? A little bit light blue like its on the first one. Which tool in PS CS 6 Extended I should use?

Thanks for taking the time to check my question and possibly answer.

Comment: I tried with brush tool but it didnt do well. Example: http://i.imgur.com/LJAPSdw.png | The original one is a lot more gradually dark/light and text is a bit lighter. Also, the original one is like using Elliptical Marquee tool to make it some kind of form of it instead of no form like I did probably?

Comment: Change the blending mode and the opacity.

Comment: I changed it a few times to just test and its still output similiar results to my try above. Isn't there a way to select the area where the text is with Elliptical marquee tool and do this like in the original image?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new document with a black background. Create a new layer, use the Elliptical Marquee Tool <kbd>M</kbd> to draw out an ellipse with your desired dimensions. Select a blue color of your choice and fill the ellipse selection with the Paint Bucket <kbd>G</kbd>. Use Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur with desired settings. You should now have the faded ellipse background for the text.

Select the Type Tool <kbd>T</kbd> to type out your text with white on a new layer. In the layers pane right click on your text layer and select Blending Options. Check the 'Outer Glow' option. Use something like [these settings](https://imgur.com/1EW6nM7), they'll depend on your text size. Make sure to use a blue that is lighter than your background ellipse.

You should have a result looking something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- open your file
- create a new layer
- draw and fill in an oval shape with blue
- blur this layer to the desired look
- set the layer blending to 'lighten'
- adjust opacity as desired